# sparql query on alignment ontology

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, owl, apache-jena

Hi I have two ontologies and one other ontology that is alignment of them.
Now I want to run some sparql query on alignment ontology to get data from both ontologies. But I don't know what should be the PREFIX is sparql ?
and how I can Access to properties ?

A part of my first ontology is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
      <!ENTITY xsd      "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
  <!ENTITY rdf      "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
  <!ENTITY rdfs     "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
  <!ENTITY dc       "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" > 
  <!ENTITY owl      "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" > ]>

  <rdf:RDF
  xmlns="http://alignapi.gforge.inria.fr/tutorial/tutorial4/ontology1.owl#"
  xml:base="http://alignapi.gforge.inria.fr/tutorial/tutorial4/ontology1.owl#"
  xmlns:rdf ="&rdf;"
  xmlns:xsd ="&xsd;"
  xmlns:rdfs    ="&rdfs;"
  xmlns:owl ="&owl;"
  xmlns:dc  ="&dc;">

<owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://alignapi.gforge.inria.fr/tutorial/tutorial4/ontology1.owl">
<dc:creator>Jérôme Euzenat</dc:creator>
<dc:description>Example for Alignment API advanced turorial</dc:description>
<dc:date>2009-07-06</dc:date>
<dc:date>2014-12-06</dc:date>
<rdfs:label>First ontology</rdfs:label>
<dc:title>ontology1.owl: a fake list of students</dc:title>
<dc:identifier  rdf:datatype="&xsd;anyURI">http://alignapi.gforge.inria.fr/tutorial/tutorial4/ontology1.owl</dc:identifier>
</owl:Ontology>
<owl:Class rdf:about="#Participante">
<rdfs:label xml:lang="es">Participante</rdfs:label>
</owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:about="#Estudiante">
<rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Participante" />
<rdfs:label xml:lang="es">Estudiante</rdfs:label>
</owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:about="#Tutor">
<rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Participante" />
<rdfs:label xml:lang="es">Professor</rdfs:label>
</owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:about="#TutorEstudiante">
<rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Estudiante" />
<rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Tutor" />
<rdfs:label xml:lang="es">Professor</rdfs:label>
</owl:Class>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="#lastname">
<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Participante" />
<rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
<rdfs:label xml:lang="es">appelido</rdfs:label>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="#firstname">
<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Participante" />
<rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
<rdfs:label xml:lang="es">nombre</rdfs:label>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="#gender">
<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Participante" />
<rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
</owl:DatatypeProperty>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="#affiliation">
<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Participante" />
<rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
</owl:DatatypeProperty>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="#city">
<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Participante" />
<rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
</owl:DatatypeProperty>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="#country">
<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Participante" />
<rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
</owl:DatatypeProperty>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="#">
<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Participante" />
<rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
</owl:DatatypeProperty>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="#year">
<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Estudiante" />
<rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
</owl:DatatypeProperty>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="#topic">
<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Participante" />
<rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
</owl:DatatypeProperty>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="#supervisor">
<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Estudiante" />
<rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
</owl:DatatypeProperty>

<Estudiante rdf:about="#Fitzgerald">
<lastname>Fitzgerald</lastname>
<firstname>Ella</firstname>
<gender>Female</gender>
<affiliation>Vanilla University of Technology</affiliation>
<city>Vanilla</city>
<country>AT</country>
<year>1</year>
<topic>Semantic Process Mining</topic>
<supervisor>Prof. Giancarlo Cetriolo</supervisor>
</Estudiante>

<Estudiante rdf:about="#Blackey">
<lastname>Blackey</lastname>
<firstname>Art</firstname>
<gender>Male</gender>
<affiliation>University of Albatra</affiliation>
<city>Albatra</city>
<country>ES</country>
<year>1</year>
<topic>Semantic Web applications</topic>
<supervisor>Paola Pomodoro</supervisor>
<supervisor>Pierluiggi Pomodoro</supervisor>
</Estudiante>
```

and I can run some query like this and get data :

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX aa:     <http://alignapi.gforge.inria.fr/tutorial/tutorial4/ontology1.owl#>

SELECT ?fn ?ln ?t ?s
WHERE {
  ?student rdf:type aa:Estudiante .
  ?student aa:firstname  ?fn .
  ?student aa:lastname  ?ln .
OPTIONAL   {   ?student aa:affiliation ?t . }
OPTIONAL   {   ?student aa:supervisor ?s . }
      }
```

my second ontology is like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
      <!ENTITY xsd      "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
      <!ENTITY rdf      "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
      <!ENTITY rdfs     "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
      <!ENTITY dc       "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" > 
      <!ENTITY owl      "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" > ]>

      <rdf:RDF
 xmlns="http://alignapi.gforge.inria.fr/tutorial/tutorial4/ontology2.owl#"
xml:base="http://alignapi.gforge.inria.fr/tutorial/tutorial4/ontology2.owl#"
    xmlns:rdf   ="&rdf;"
    xmlns:xsd   ="&xsd;"
    xmlns:rdfs  ="&rdfs;"
    xmlns:owl   ="&owl;"
    xmlns:dc    ="&dc;">

    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://alignapi.gforge.inria.fr/tutorial/tutorial4/ontology2.owl">
<dc:creator>Jérôme Euzenat</dc:creator>
<dc:description>Example for Alignment API advanced turorial</dc:description>
<dc:date>2009-07-06</dc:date>
<dc:date>2014-12-05</dc:date>
<rdfs:label>Second ontology</rdfs:label>
<dc:title>ontology2.owl: another fake list of students</dc:title>
<dc:identifier         rdf:datatype="&xsd;anyURI">http://alignapi.gforge.inria.fr/tutorial/tutorial4/ontology2.owl</dc:identifier>
</owl:Ontology>

<owl:Class rdf:about="#Student">
<rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person" />
<rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Student</rdfs:label>
</owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:about="#Teacher">
<rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person" />
<owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="#Student" />
<rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Staff</rdfs:label>
</owl:Class>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="#name">
<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person" />
<rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
</owl:DatatypeProperty>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="#first-name">
<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person" />
<rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
</owl:DatatypeProperty>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="#gender">
<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person" />
<rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
</owl:DatatypeProperty>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="#institution">
<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person" />
<rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
</owl:DatatypeProperty>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="#city-of-study">
<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Student" />
<rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
</owl:DatatypeProperty>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="#country-of-study">
<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Student" />
<rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
</owl:DatatypeProperty>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="#year-in-phd">
<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Student" />
<rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
</owl:DatatypeProperty>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="#topics-of-interest">
<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person" />
<rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
</owl:DatatypeProperty>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="#phd-advisor">
<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Student" />
<rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
</owl:DatatypeProperty>

<Student rdf:about="#dkral">
<name>Krall</name>
<first-name>Diana</first-name>
<gender>Female</gender>
<institution>Royal University of Worchester sauce</institution>
<city-of-study>Worchester sauce</city-of-study>
<country-of-study>GB</country-of-study>
<year-in-phd>1</year-in-phd>
<topics-of-interest>OWL and SKOS: Exploring the relationship between       formal and informal knowledge representation</topics-of-interest>
<phd-advisor>Dr. A. Verdura</phd-advisor>
<phd-advisor>C. Fragola</phd-advisor>
</Student>
```

And I can run some sparql query on it.

And my Alignment ontology is :

```
<rdf:RDF
xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">

<owl:Ontology rdf:about="">
<rdfs:comment>Matched ontologies</rdfs:comment>
<rdfs:comment>Generated by      fr.inrialpes.exmo.align.renderer.OWLAxiomsRendererVisitor</rdfs:comment>
<rdfs:comment>method: fr.inrialpes.exmo.align.ObjectAlignment#toObject</rdfs:comment>
<owl:imports rdf:resource="http://alignapi.gforge.inria.fr/tutorial/tutorial4/ontology1.owl"/>
<owl:imports rdf:resource="http://alignapi.gforge.inria.fr/tutorial/tutorial4/ontology2.owl"/>
 </owl:Ontology> 
 <owl:DatatypeProperty     rdf:about="http://alignapi.gforge.inria.fr/tutorial/tutorial4/ontology1.owl#  supervisor">
     <owl:equivalentProperty      rdf:resource="http://alignapi.gforge.inria.fr/tutorial/tutorial4/ontology2.o       wl#phd-advisor"/>
       </owl:DatatypeProperty>
```

and my problem is I don't know the sparql query on alignment ontology should be like what and what is structure ?

I use Apache Jena interface and my piece of code for sparql query is :

```
OntModel model = (OntModel)ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_RULE_INF, null );
    // Load ontology 1
    //OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_RDFS_INF or no arguments to see the difference...
    model.read( "file:Ontologies/ontology1.owl" );
    // Query in ontology 1
    displayQueryAnswer( model, QueryFactory.read( "file:Ontologies/query.sparql" ) );
   // Execute the query and obtain results
    QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create( query, model );
    ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
    // Output query results 
    ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);
    if ( qe != null ) qe.close();
    }
```

I can fetch data using SPARQL query on *ontology1.owl*

but I don't know how to write SPARQL query to fetch data from alignment ontology!
Can anyone give an example ?

Comment: ??? I don't understand the question. You want to run which SPARQL query on which ontology? On the "Alignment ontology" the same SPARQL queries that you already have for the two ontologies? If yes, you need a SPARQL engine/triple store/API that allows for OWL imports, otherwise it obviously doesn't work. It's not clear which API you use.

Comment: I just update my question, I just want sparql example for fetching data from alignment ontology because using previous query I couldn't fetch anything!

Comment: From the documentation, Jena supports OWL imports (https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/). It's still not clear what does not work. Your code shows how you run a SPARQL query on ontology1. What happens if you run it on the alignment ontology, i.e. load the ontology and run the SPARQL query? What does not work for which query?

Comment: I run exactly the query I have ran on ontology1, on alignment and it return nothing. I don't know It's correct to expect the query I run I ontology1, running on alignment have result ? Or I should edit my query ? Using the reasoner I found the alignment have 47 instances but I don't know how to fetch them ?

Comment: Ehm, next time it would be more helpful if you tell us that you're doing a tutorial of the Alignment API - some people might already have done this: http://alignapi.gforge.inria.fr/tutorial/tutorial4/ Moreover, have you read the line marked in red? There it's mentioned that Jena has some problems in resolving the imports. This might be outdated, but the even information that there was a problem would be a contribution...

Comment: Ok, I tried it and it works for me. I loaded the merged ontology and run exactly the same SPARQL query. Which Jena version do you use?

Comment: I really appreciate your answers !  Yes I saw that red line but since the data is stored in alignment ontology, there should be a way to fetch it by SPARQL query. I use Alignment API 4.7 and I think It use Jena 2.9.0. I run exactly the code that is in tutorial, It answers for ontology1 and ontology2, but as the red line says, it doesn't work for alignment ontology !? Thanks

Comment: Ok, I can only tell you that it works with Apache Jena 3.1.0 on my machine

Comment: Thanks, May I have your piece of code for running SPARQLs on ontologies in Apache Jena ?

Comment: It is exactly the code from the tutorial with a minor adaption due to Jena version 3 changes(`ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results);`). Can you please try to run it with Apache Jena 3.1.0?

Comment: It's OK my friend, I use Jena version 3 and it works! God bless you!

Comment: I have one more question, you know when we load alignment ontology using Jena it fetch ontology1 and ontology2 by their URL from [http://alignapi.gforge.inria.fr/tutorial/tutorial4/](http://alignapi.gforge.inria.fr/tutorial/tutorial4/) and actually connecting to internet is needed. How can I change alignment ontology to use my local ontology1 and ontology2 on my file system and not from URI ?

Comment: You should know that you can refer to any file on your system by a URI. So I don't see the problem. And as always, the first entry point is the documentation: https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Imports